# Using C# to Create Reports:create reports in C# with grouping Data with all Columns

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, rdlc

I want to create report that show data group by each column and total them

My select Data in SQL Server is:

```
Select sa,sb,sc,id from tbl
```

How do I can crate my report in rdlc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use 'Group BY' With `rollup` Or 'Cube' Data Grouped by each column
in cube data grouped by all column with permutation of all column for your example grouped by
1-sa
2-sb
3-sc
4-sa,sb
5-sa,sc
6-sb,sc
7-sa,sb,sc

```
Select sa,sb,sc,id from tbl group by cube (sa,sb,sc)
```

if you use rollup data group by sort of column
for your example
1-sa
2-sa,sb
3-sa,sb,sc

```
Select sa,sb,sc,id from tbl group by rollup (sa,sb,sc)
```